# Wordpress function get_post_gallery() does not register post's gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to extract the images contained in a gallery block while maintaining their correct order. Since get_children() and get_attached_media() do not seem to register when the image order is changed in wp-admin, I'm trying to use get_post_gallery() instead.

**My problem is that the function returns false, even though the post does have a gallery.**

I tried both the example and the plain usage from  [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery). Currently, my entire single.php looks like this:

```
<?php
get_header(); //html head etc
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); //the loop
    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
    echo get_post_gallery();
else :
    echo (the_ID() . " has no gallery.");
endif; 
endwhile;
endif;  
?>
```

… which results in "*ID* has no gallery" every time.

However, the output of `print_r($post->post_content);` does include the following, which seems to confirm that there is in a fact a gallery:

```
<!-- wp:gallery {"ids":[80,81,82]} -->
<figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-3 is-cropped">
        <ul class ="blocks-gallery-grid">
        <!-- … -->
```

I'm also attaching a screenshot from wp-admin to make sure I don't misunderstand what constitutes a gallery.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As pointed out by Samuel, the issue is that I am using Gutenberg. See this post for a universal solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post_gallery()` works only for native galleries which have been created in classig WYSIWYG editor. You can find more about it [there](https://wordpress.org/support/article/the-wordpress-gallery/). Hovewer, if you create Gallery via Gutenberg, it create the whole HTML code instead of classic editor gallery which create shortcode like this: `[gallery ids="400097,400052,400051"]` . Functions `get_post_gallery()`, `get_post_galleries()` and `get_post_gallery_images()` works only on classic galleries added via native shortcode.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!

With that new information, I found a solution that works for both classic and Gutenberg galleries: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325428/get-post-gallery-with-gutenberg

Comment: `get_post_galleries()` and therefore `get_post_gallery()` support galleries created in the block editor (Gutenberg) as of WordPress 5.9. Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43826#comment:58

Answer (score 0):

Are you only trying to display the gallery block as opposed to all content? If so, maybe try this?

```
  <?php
  get_header(); //html head etc

  if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); //the loop
    if (has_block('gallery', $post->post_content)) {
      echo 'yes, there is a gallery';
      $post_blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);
      foreach ($post_blocks as $post_block){
        if ($post_block['blockName'] == 'core/gallery'){
          echo do_shortcode( $post_block['innerHTML'] );
        }
      }
    }
    // if there is not a gallery block do this
    else {
        echo 'no gallery';
    }
  endwhile;
  endif;
  get_footer();
  ?>
```

I got some inspiration from reading [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325708) post btw.